# can I use curl_multi/multi_socket with libevent

Tags: curl, libevent

I'm using libevent2 for building a server, and I'm trying to enable the server to use libcurl asynchronously, and I'm wondering about how I do that with libevent2.

I would like to be able to get curl to send events so I can inspect the current state.

Update: I figured it out

http://github.com/mathgladiator/node.ocaml/blob/master/ext/sandbox.c

Comment: I took a look at your link, doesnt the line `while(CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM == curl_multi_perform(ce->multi_handle, &(ce->still_running)));`  cause you to starv other libevent tasks/callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the multi_socket API was made to be used by event-based systems such as libevent, so yes

Comment: Took a bit, but I figured it out.